# Insert mode toggle in a CMD window always reverts to insert mode = on in Windows 11

Tags: windows, cmd

Right click on a CMD icon on the Win 11 desktop, click on Properties -> Options tab.  About half way down is the "Insert Mode".  Whether this is checked or not, insert is always on at the resulting CMD prompt.

Comment: Thanks, I changed InsertMode to 0, and then restarted a CMD window.  However InsertMode is still on.  (Note I have already set it to be off in the CMD icon Properties).   Note Win 11 only.

Comment: ( I know this isn't a programming question, but I just got upgraded to Win11 and there are some technical changes I thought others here would know how to solve )